# SELECT statement in SQL works but SELECT INTO statement in PLSQL doesn't

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql

I have the below select statement which works in SQLPLUS in my schema

```
select count(1) from gv$lock where id1 ='202';
```

But the same select statement in my function in same schema FN_GET_LOCK throws error "table or view does not exist" in PLSQL

```
select count(1) into l_lockcnt from gv$lock where id1 = l_lock_hold;
```

Any idea how to make the SQL statement work in PLSQL

This question is not duplicate since I am not getting "insufficient privileges error"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you've got the `SELECT` privilege on `gv$lock` via a role. If that's so, well - it won't work in named PL/SQL procedures. You'll have to grant that privilege **directly** to the user.

**[EDIT: About roles]**

Generally speaking - not only about *roles* - a good resource for further investigation is the dictionary. Here's a sample query you might use to find that info:

```
SQL> select * from dictionary where lower(table_name) like '%role%';

TABLE_NAME                     COMMENTS
------------------------------ --------------------------------------------------
DBA_CONNECT_ROLE_GRANTEES      Information regarding which users are granted CONN
                               ECT

DBA_ROLES                      All Roles which exist in the database
DBA_ROLE_PRIVS                 Roles granted to users and roles
DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_ROLES        All scheduler jobs in the database by database rol
                               e

USER_ROLE_PRIVS                Roles granted to current user
ROLE_ROLE_PRIVS                Roles which are granted to roles
ROLE_SYS_PRIVS                 System privileges granted to roles
ROLE_TAB_PRIVS                 Table privileges granted to roles
SESSION_ROLES                  Roles which the user currently has enabled.

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Let's create a role and grant it some privileges:

```
SQL> create role rl_scott_sel;

Role created.

SQL> grant select on emp to rl_scott_sel;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant select on bonus to rl_scott_Sel;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

OK, so - what does the `ROLE_TAB_PRIVS` contain? It looks like a good starting point, reading the comments above.

```
SQL> select role, owner, table_name, privilege
  2  from role_Tab_privs;

ROLE            OWNER      TABLE_NAME PRIVILEGE
--------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
RL_SCOTT_SEL    SCOTT      BONUS      SELECT
RL_SCOTT_SEL    SCOTT      EMP        SELECT

SQL>
```

Comment: is it possible to find out the role and all the tables to which it has select privilege

Comment: I've added some more info into the answer; have a look, please.